# How to define a math expression for repeated use in bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
%   bookmarks=true,           % show bookmarks bar?
    bookmarksopen=true,
    unicode=true             % non--Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{
    \texorpdfstring{Math symbols $\sum, \int$}%
    {Math symbols sum, integral}
}
\section{Example: %
\texorpdfstring{$\{[\phi(t),p(\cdot)]\}$}
    {$\{[\textphi(t),p(\textcdot)]\}$}
}

\section{Example: %
\texorpdfstring{$[\phi(t),p(\cdot)]$}
    {$\{[\textphi(t),p(\textcdot)]\}$}
}


\end{document}
```

I have several section/subsection headings with math expressions like the above. Is there a way to make a general definition of `\phi` (or `lambda` or any other maths notation), so that `\phi` is a math symbol in the article and a text `phi` in bookmark?

If I have to do this every time, that means I have to write all section names **twice**, which was a bit unpleasant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most symbols are available in Unicode except for the subscript C:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  bookmarksopen=true,
  unicode=true             % non--Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures  

\section{Math symbols $\sum, \int$}
\section{$\{\phi(t), p(\cdot)\}$}  
\section{$\{\phi(t), p(t)\}$}
\section{$\{[\phi(t + h), \lambda(t + h)]\texorpdfstring_{\_}C\}$}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Then the warnings

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 17.
```

can be ignored. They can be removed by using `\ensuremath{...}` instead of `$...$`.

Option `psdextra` adds support for many, many math symbols. Package `bookmark` improves the update behavior (and provides more features).

### Character shapes in bookmarks

The bookmarks are displayed with a font, which the PDF viewer chooses, the PDF file only contains a simple string (with encoding PDFDocEncoding or Unicode).
The case of `\phi` is ambiguous, because it could stand for several Unicode code points:

- φ U+03C6   GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI
- ϕ U+03D5   GREEK PHI SYMBOL
- ɸ U+0278   LATIN SMALL LETTER PHI

`hyperref` maps `\phi` to `\textphi`, which uses the text variant U+03C6.
It can be redefined to return the math symbol U+03D5:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  psdextra,
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{
  bookmarksopen=true,
  unicode=true             % non--Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\phi{\unichar{"03D5}}%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{Math symbols $\sum, \int$}
\section{$\{\phi(t), p(\cdot)\}$}
\section{$\{\phi(t), p(t)\}$}
\section{$\{[\phi(t + h), \lambda(t + h)]\texorpdfstring_{\_}C\}$}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: A tiny extra thing. Is there a better(similar) look `phi` to the one in the content? The current `phi` in the bookmark is just too different to the one in the content. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed your updated answer. Thank you very much!